# How can I send image-containing markdown files to another computer?

Tags: markdown

I have a problem, I have prepared my .md files on my first PC. Now that I want to work on them on my second PC, the image paths are not recognized as they are related to my first PC. I don't know how to send my .md files to other computers without losing my images. It would be very nice if someone helps me as I am new to markdown.

Comment: Well, you'll need to send the images too. Are you using absolute paths or relative paths in your Markdown file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use absolute paths. I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Consider that using absolute paths means the images need to be at a very specific location to work. Relative paths probably make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Convert all links to *relative* paths, organize everything in a folder in the same directory as your file, and zip them together.
- Convert your file to PDF, this allows you to embed everything, including fonts and images.